# Make vertical UIStackView ignore the height of it's child when expanding

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a vertical `UIStackView` that have multiple view element

As you can see on image below, I have a small view with a background color of yellow inside a `UIStackView`.

What I want to do is when I adjust the height of that yellow `UIView`, the position of the view below it will not change just like on the second image.

[image]

Here is the second image, As you can see, I make the yellow `UIView` bigger but the green `UIView` didn't change its position and make the yellow `UIView` cover it.

[image]

The question is, Is there a way to do that inside the `UIStackView`?

Because when I expand the yellow `UIView` inside the `UIStackView`, the top of the green `UIView` was always on the bottom of the yellow `UIView`.

Note: That yellow need to be expanded even until it reach the blue `UIView`

Comment: what distribution mode are you using?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Fill

Comment: Add your code related to this

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha I just created it using the interface builder, I create a vertical UIStackView with 0 constraints to all sides and add UIViews inside it

Comment: I've edited your question. Could you try to rephrase your question? I can't comprehend your question a bit. Perhaps make the whole explanation simpler and shorter. It seems you want to do multiple things. When resizing the yellow view, do you want the green view and the views below it to move too?

Comment: @Glenn I want to resize the yellow `UIView` without moving the position of any other `UIView`s in the `UIStackView`

Comment: @MarkDylanBMercado - no, you cannot do it that way. Well, you *could* by extending a yellow layer beyond the bounds of its view, but bad idea. What you probably want to do is embed the yellow and green views in another `UIView`, allow that view to fill the space between red and blue, and position your yellow view on top of the green view.